# S3 Delete & HDFS to S3 Copy

Tags: airflow

As a part of my `Spark` *pipeline*, I have to perform following tasks on `EMR` / `S3`:

1. **Delete**: (Recursively) Delete all files / directories under a given `S3 bucket`
2. **Copy**: Copy contents of a directory (subdirectories & files) to a given `S3 bucket`

---

Based on my current knowledge, `Airflow` doesn't provide `operator`s / `hook`s for these tasks. I therefore plan to implement them as follows:

1. **Delete**: Extend [`S3Hook`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/S3_hook.html#S3Hook) to add a function that performs `aws s3 rm` on specified `S3 bucket`
2. **Copy**: Use [`SSHExecuteOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/ssh_execute_operator.html) to perform `hadoop distcp`

---

My questions are:

- I reckon that the tasks I intend to perform are quite *primitive*. Are these functionalities already provided by `Airflow`?
- If not, is there a better way to achieve this than what I plan to do?

---

I'm using:

- `Airflow 1.9.0` [`Python 3.6.6`] (will upgrade to `Airflow 1.10` once [it is released](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@airflow.apache.org:lte=1M:release))
- `EMR 5.13.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `delete` is a primitive operation yes but not the `hadoop distcp`. To answer your questions:

1. No airflow does not have functions on the s3 hook to perform these actions.
2. By creating your own plugin to extend the s3_hook and also using the ssh operator to perform the distcp is, in my opinion, a good way to do this.

Not sure why the standards S3_Hook does not have a delete function. It MAY be because [s3 provides an "eventually consistent" Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) (probably not the reason but good to keep in mind anyway)